# How to execute batch file on server from my local computer?

Tags: batch-file, execution

What would be the best way to execute a specified batch script that are located on a server from my local machine?

I tried using PHP, and I had admin issues.  I need something that can specify what batch needs execute, enter it then the batch file will get executed on my server.

Could you give some examples, or any site that works?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Use a UNC path.   For instance, `\\remoteserver\c$\path\to.bat`, I used the C$ admin share in case you don't have regular sharing enabled.

Comment: Do you have access through SSH on port 22? If yes, you could use plink tool to connect and execute commands on remote server.

Comment: Could you explain UNC path a little more? Requirements? I'm new to it, so is it easy to learn?  Any important details?